# Workaround for question offered in comments, what to do with question?

Tags: discussion

Specifically, this question: [Restore %APPDATA% to AppData/Roaming folder](https://superuser.com/questions/1023201/restore-appdata-to-appdata-roaming-folder). I am relatively new to SE, so I don't know what the appropriate course of action is to take here.

I had a problem that I couldn't find on Google, so I came here to ask my question. I received a downvote (I wonder why, if you see any reason for it, please explain), but someone did help me find the solution in the comments. It appeared to be a user-related problem and making a new user fixed the problem. I have made this new user and deleted the problematic user. I asked the commenter to write an answer, but he or she didn't do so.

What to do with this question? I see three possible courses of action, but I am unsure, which is the best.

- Delete the question. This was my first thought, but I'm not sure deleting is a good call.
- Close the question as no longer answerable. I think this would be a good choice, since it's a bad question (received downvote). This on the other hand, would make it harder to find for people with the same problem.
- Someone could answer the question and I will accept it.

Comment: You could always answer it yourself

Comment: If you don't feel comfortable about taking credit for someone else's work, you can attribute the answer to userXXXX's comment, and then set the answer itself to community wiki when you post it. This is one of the cases CW was intended for, and doing this means you won't get any rep points from votes on it (because you've waived ownership of the answer).

Comment: If I want credit, I post an answer, you can safeuly assume I don't want any credit if I don't post an answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I will answer it once I'm back on the computer.

Comment: Anyone can use someone else's comment for their own answer, this happens quite often when users like Ramhound do not want the rep. Its an accepted practice here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [Answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer):

> **Can I answer my own question?**
>
> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer
>   their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the
>   answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so
>   that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly
>   okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.
>
> To encourage people to do this, there is a checkbox at the bottom of
>   the page every time you ask a question. If you have more than 15
>   reputation and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says
>   "Answer your own question" at the bottom of the Ask Question page.
>   Type in your answer, then submit both question and answer together.
>
> Alternatively, you may go back and add an answer to your own question
>   at any time.
>
> You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do
>   so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better
>   solution to your problem!